# Program with graphics being aborted, even though XInitThreads was called

Tags: c, xlib, bgi

I have just started using Graphics in C, and I encountered this error while running a simple program that draws concentric circles:

```
user@user:~/Documents/C$ gcc circle.c -lX11 -lgraph
user@user:~/Documents/C$ ./a.out
[xcb] Unknown sequence number while processing queue
[xcb] Most likely this is a multi-threaded client and XInitThreads has not been called
[xcb] Aborting, sorry about that. a.out: ../../src/xcb_io.c:274: poll_for_event:
      Assertion '!xcb_xlib_threads_sequence_lost' failed.
Aborted (core dumped)
```

And:

```
[xcb] Unknown sequence number while processing queue
[xcb] Most likely this is a multi-threaded client and XInitThreads has not been called
[xcb] Aborting, sorry about that. a.out: ../../src/xcb_io.c:274: poll_for_event: Assertion `!xcb_xlib_threads_sequence_lost' failed.
```

I looked up some forums on the internet and they suggested that adding `#include<X11/Xlib.h>` and calling `XInitThreads()` in the beginning of `main()` would solve the problem, But I still get the **same** error while running.

I've attached the code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<graphics.h>
#include<X11/Xlib.h>

int main()
{
    XInitThreads();
    int gd=DETECT, gm,r,x;
    initgraph(&gd,&gm,NULL);

    setbkcolor(WHITE);
    setcolor(BLACK);
    for(r=10;r<100;r+=10)
    {
        circle(150,150,r);
    }
    scanf("%d",&x);
    closegraph();

    return 0;
}
```

I use Ubuntu 14.04 and GCC for compiling.

Comment: This might be helpful:
https://cgit.freedesktop.org/xorg/lib/libX11/tree/src/xcb_io.c#n212

Ownership of the event queue (if your library uses XCB) is required, and is one possible reason for this error if other threads are holding it.

Comment: You could try ignoring the error and simply entering the value your program takes as input (scanf), it worked for me. If your program doesn't take any input value then the answer by DrPaul should work

Answer (score 5):

I added the following call before `closegraph()`;

`wait_for_char()`;

where:

```
void wait_for_char()
{

    //Wait for a key press
    int in = 0;

    while (in == 0) {
        in = getchar();
    }
}
```

This solves the problem without having to call `XInitThreads()`.
Don't ask me why. But I use the `wait_for_key()` anyway to give me time to look!

Comment: Still didn't fix it for me